# Is there a way to create a Beanstalk configuration template outside of an "application"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I think I'm missing something here with Beanstalk's concept of "application"

I have about 30 apps. I want them to be in Beanstalk.

I was going to create 30 Beanstalk "applications" and deploy each app to its own application (with its own environment).

But Beanstalk configuration templates MUST be bound to a beanstalk application? That makes no sense. About 80% of the Beanstalk environment settings for these 30 apps are the same so naturally I want to create a configuration template they all can use for default settings.

Well, I can't do that because templates need to be attached to a specific application.

So should I have ONE application and have each of my 30 apps be deployed to their own "environment" under that single application? This is the only way I can use a single configuration template? Is this the right way to use Beanstalk? It feels wrong because of the terms "application" and "environment".

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about one application for 30 apps depends on your use case ofcourse. How I use EB is one application which has a preproduction environment and a production environment (within the same application);

You probably want multiple applications with each an production environment.  If you would setup these 30 apps through the AWS console you would have bad time. Luckly you can write all the configuration you are doing down in .yaml; to help you get started I can point you to the documentation of AWS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/beanstalk-environment-configuration-advanced.html